# Calculating shaded cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, google-sheets-custom-function

I am using Google Spreadsheets to create a matrix (time/activity) as a daily schedule for staff to sign into.

Is there a formula to calculate the number of cells in a column that are shaded (or not shaded) a certain color?

For example: 20 of the cells are gray and 31 are not gray (shaded any other color) and instead of manually counting them, it calculates this at the bottom of reach column.

Comment: The problem with the @w0lf's solution comes from the cache. The function is not ready to get live updates. I tried to gain that ability by [adding "now()" as an extra parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11060267/1365642) but it didn't work.

Comment: I can't answer so I'll just leave a comment. If the cells dont have any text, it is easier to add any text inside with the same color as the background (so it is hidden) and then you just do a simple =counta() to count non empty cells. If course this is very specific depending on the case.

Answer (score 22):

I have found a way to do this, using the scripting functionality that Google Spreadsheet provides.

Here's how to do it:

- open your spreadsheet
- in the menu, go to Tools -> Script Editor...; this will open a new window that allows you to enter code
- copy the code below
- paste the code in the Script Editor window and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save it
- close the Script editor windows and go back to the spreadsheet

Code:

```
function getBackgroundColor(rangeSpecification) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification);
  return cell.getBackground();
}

function sumWhereBackgroundColorIs(color, rangeSpecification) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification);
  var x = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= range.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= range.getNumColumns(); j++) {
      var cell = range.getCell(i, j);
      if(cell.getBackground() == color)
        x += parseFloat(cell.getValue());
    }
  }
  return x;
}

function countCellsWithBackgroundColor(color, rangeSpecification) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification);
  var x = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= range.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= range.getNumColumns(); j++) {
      var cell = range.getCell(i, j);
      if(cell.getBackground() == color)
        x++;
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

After following the above steps, you have three more functions available in the spreadsheet:

- `countCellsWithBackgroundColor(<color>, <range specification>)`
- `sumWhereBackgroundColorIs(<color>, <range specification>)`
- `getBackgroundColor(<cell specification>)`

Please note that `<range specification>` and `<cell specification>` are expressed in **A1** notation, and **must be enclosed in quotes**.

For example, to get the count of all the cells in the range B2:F13 that have the background color set to *white*, you should enter the following formula:

```
=countCellsWithBackgroundColor("white", "B2:F13")
```

and to compute the sum of the same cells, use the formula:

```
=sumWhereBackgroundColorIs("white", "B2:F13")
```

Some cells may not have the background set to a color such as 'white', 'gray', but a RGB color like `#6fa8dc`. You cannot guess what the color is, so if you want to find out the color for a cell (for example, `B9`), you should enter this formula in a cell:

```
=getBackgroundColor("B9")
```

and afterwards use this value as a parameter to the two functions above.

It appears that if a cell's background color is a "theme color," `getBackground()` incorrectly always returns `#ffffff`. I haven't found a way around this other than to use a color from the standard set.

Again, note the quotes in all above examples; without them, the formulas would not work.

Comment: I have been trying to follow your hints, but in the field I use the formula I receive #NUM!, do you know why is that?
I tried to do some research, but I couldn't find exact answer for that.
Thanks a million, dami

Comment: @Dami can you post your formula here? Also, check the spelling - I think the formula names are case sensitive

Comment: Getting just a zero here, despite following the instructions...

Comment: The `getBackgroundColor()` is deprecated. Perhaps you can update the code?

Comment: When I change the background color to another value, the sum is not updated. Is there a way to automatically update the sum when I do some changes?

Comment: How would you do this with the new Spreadsheet? Script gallery was replaced by addon store, and the script editor is completely new.

Comment: @molnarg The addon store is not yet available for me.

Comment: how can we make this so that when the cell is edited, it will run the script again and update the value? It's currently unaware of any changes made until the page is refreshed

Comment: @Oneezy Here's a solution: https://github.com/clupasq/GoogleApps_SumByColor/blob/master/README.md#auto-updates. Not pretty, but it works.

Comment: @w0lf Great! I actually got this working shortly after by this technique: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/S5r0fHkGKF0 ,,, i'll give that link you posted a go. Yeah, these tricks are definitely not pretty...but they will get the job done for now. Thanks

Comment: `getBackgroundColor()` is now `getBackground()`.

Also, it appears that if a cell's background color is a "theme color," getBackground() incorrectly always returns #ffffff. I haven't found a way around this other than to use a color from the standard set.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to directly count the cells with a specific color in Google Docs.

What makes them shaded. Is it automatic? If they have a value they are automatically shaded? If that is the case you can use the counta() function to count any cell with a value. If there is a more complex set of rules involved you may need to use the countif() function.

**Note:you may have to take into account any extra rows at the top or the bottom of the column**