# Google sheet - highlihghting cell if in the same row other cell not empty

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-cell-format

I'm trying to make a worksheet where I log shift hours.

I made columns with dates and to each date a row of hours

I want the date text to be green if in the same row a cell is not empty..

The code I used here apply only for column B and I don't know how to do it so the other columns applied as well `=NOT(ISBLANK(B4:B43))`

If possible.. I would also prefer to do it so I will not have to add any letters like `-` inside the cell but only color the cells

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting that applies to your column range (All the dates). In my example this is `A2:A6`. Then I created the custom formula `=COUNTA(B2:F2)` to make sure a cell is colored when one or more cells in its corresponding row are not empty.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

This solution is dependent on the cells not being blank so only colors won't work. Detecting if a cell has a specific color using the by default available functions is not possible as far as I know. You could however create a `Google Apps Script` script to use in the sheet. For this I recommend looking at [Calculating shaded cells](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23881/calculating-shaded-cells).

Personally I recommend just using the first approach as this is a lot easier.